# Browser back button and state retains?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have an eCommerce system where I have listed the Recently Viewed Count and Items as viewer browse its details page.

When the user had viewed any item using any browser and click the Back button of the Browser then, recently viewed items module doesn't get refresh at all. But on reloading the url(Refresh), the module gets refreshed and shows the recently viewed items and Count?

Answer (score 2):

Look to the [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/). This framework uses HTML 5 browser's features and can handle back button events.

Comment: ok i ll try on that .js anatomy

Answer (score -1):

Going back does not refresh any data, so you'll need to ask for the information from the server each time you wan't the information updated, for example using Ajax.

Comment: Any comment as to the downvote? Technically this is correct, if the data is cached and the page makes no requests then the back button isn't going to appear to do anything if the previous page is the same as the current. This answer may not be overly helpful but it's not incorrect.